# Paypal php IPN not updating my database

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So, I am using Paypal IPN. But it is not working for updating my database (cart and invoice). Would anyone help me to debug my code, please?  It's sending successful IPN's to paypal, But isn't updating anything. Here's the code:

Our code on payment page:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="frm" id="frm" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="fin@mycoupon.com.hk" />
<?

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart, member, product
where cart.member_id = member.member_id
And cart.product_id = product.product_id
And member.email = '$_SESSION[member]'
And cart.status = 'cart'
And cart.quantity > (SELECT quantity FROM quantity where quantity.quantity_id = cart.quantity_id)
"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$del_cart_id = $row['cart_id'];
$del_product_id = $row['product_id'];
$del_member_id = $row['member_id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET status = 'delete', last_modified = now()
where member_id = '$del_member_id'
And product_id = '$del_product_id'
And cart_id = '$del_cart_id'
"); 
}

$i =1;
$cartresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart, product
where cart.member_id = '$member_id'
And cart.product_id = product.product_id
And cart.invoice_id = '$invoice'
And cart.status = 'cart'
And cart.quantity <= (SELECT quantity FROM quantity where quantity.quantity_id = cart.quantity_id)

"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($cartresult))
{
echo'<input type="hidden" name="item_number_'.$i.'" value="'.$row['cart_id'].'">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="item_name_'.$i.'" value="'.$row['productname'].'">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="amount_'.$i.'" value="'.$row['dprice'].'">';
echo'<input type="hidden" name="quantity_'.$i.'" value="'.$row['quantity'].'">';
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET final_price = '$row[dprice]', last_modified = now()
where member_id = '$row[member_id]'
And product_id = '$row[product_id]'
And cart_id = '$row[cart_id]'
"); 
$i++;
}

$cartresult_rows = mysql_num_rows($cartresult); 

?>

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="HKD">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="HK">
<input type="hidden" name="return" id="return" value="http://www.mycoupon.com.hk/finish.php">   
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.mycoupon.com.hk/checkout_step3.php">    
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.mycoupon.com.hk/notify_return.php">

<? if ($cartresult_rows > 0) {?>    
<script language="javascript">
setTimeout("frm.submit();",1000); 
</script>
<? } else {
echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="0; index.php">';
}
?>
</form>
```

Our code on notify_return page (Update page):

```
header("content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');


// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}


// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length:" . strlen($req) ."\r\n\r\n";


// If testing on Sandbox use:
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables

$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$payment_amount= $_POST['payment_amount'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];

//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email = "fin@mycoupon.com.hk"; 


//email address to which debug emails are sent to
function db_connect(){
$link_id=mysql_connect('xxx','xxx','xxxx');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
if(!mysql_select_db('mycouponshop', $link_id)){
echo mysql_errno($link_id).": " . mysql_error($link_id);
}
return $link_id;
if (!$link_id)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}   
}

$link = db_connect();



if (!$fp) {
//HTTP error
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
if ($payment_status == "Refunded") {
mysql_query("UPDATE invoice SET cmd='$payment_status' WHERE txn_id='$txn_id'");
exit();
}

for($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++){
$cart_id = $_POST['item_number_'.$i];   
mysql_query("UPDATE cart SET status = 'finish' WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'");
}   


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE cart_id = '$cart_id'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{   
$invoice_id = $row['invoice_id'];
$memebr_id = $row['memebr_id'];
}


mysql_query("UPDATE invoice SET txn_id = '$txn_id',cmd = '$payment_status', pay_user='$payer_email', payment='paypal' , last_modified = now() where invoice_id = '$invoice_id'");   




}

// if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

}
}
fclose ($fp);
}

mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res - $payment_status\n $req");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this article on [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) for tips on testing within a browser.  This will allow you to set break points and figure out what is running and what's not, as well as see any errors on screen so you can resolve them accordingly.